# How to add hover event listener to trigger event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a hover event listener to the code below so that when I hover over the link tag, it triggers the action to expand the submenu. I tried hover and mouseover and neither worked. Click seems to work fine though, Im not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
Array.prototype.slice.call( this.menuItems ).forEach( function( el, i ) {
    var trigger = el.querySelector( 'a' );
    if( self.touch ) {
    ``trigger``.addEventListener( 'touchstart', function( ev ) { 
        self._openMenu( this, ev ); } );
    }
    else {
        trigger.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) { self._openMenu( this, ev ); });
    }
});

window.addEventListener('resize', function( ev ) { 
    self._resizeHandler(); 
});
```

Answer (score -11, accepted):

Don't punish yourself like this. Use a library like jQuery to attach eventhandlers to elements. Mouseover and hover are both supported by jQuery. Don't reinvent the wheel and build upon existing solutions like bootstrap to implement basic functionality like expanding a submenu.

Answer (score 7):

```
trigger.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
   self._openMenu(this, ev);
});

                    Write

trigger.addEventListener('mouseover', function(ev) {
   self._openMenu(this, ev);
});
```

Replace ***click event*** by ***mouseover event***